# Variable in outer function not modifiable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

If I have a variable in an outer function, and an internal function that changes that variable, why does that variable revert back to its original value?

```
// Check which type of event registration browser supports
function addEvent(eventTarget, eventType, eventHandler){
    if (window.addEventListener){
        eventTarget.addEventListener(eventType, eventHandler);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent){
        var eventType = "on" + eventType;
        eventTarget.attachEvent(eventType, eventHandler);
    }
}

// Check if browser supports DOMContentLoaded
var DOMContentLoadedSupported = "no";

addEvent(document, "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    DOMContentLoadedSupported = "yes";
})

alert(DOMContentLoadedSupported) // alerts "no" not "yes". Why??            
​
```

Comment: it will alert "no" until the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function will modify the variable, but that will happen AFTER your alert, so you see "No" in the alert cause the alert happens before the variable gets modified.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of `DOMContentLoaded` is to fire before anything else such as an alert? I'm not understanding why the alert would happen first.

Comment: @user1019031 no the point of `DOMContentLoaded` is to fire when DOM Content has been Loaded. You can check for support synchronously with `var DOMContentLoadedSupported = "addEventListener" in document;`.